# Is it possible to ask for only certain columns from an ActiveRecord association?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, associations

consider

```
def Foo
  has_one :user
end
```

let's say i only want a `Foo`'s `User`'s name, and not any of the other columns. so i want

```
SELECT name FROM "users" WHERE "prices"."id" = 123
```

but doing `foo.user.name` will give me

```
SELECT * FROM "users" WHERE "prices"."id" = 123
```

is there any slick way to use the association to get only one column? if not, then i have to do:

```
User.where(id: foo.user_id).pluck(:name).first
```

Answer (score 4):

In general you can specify what columns you want to select using the .select method, like:

```
User.select(:name).where(...)
```

This will return just the values from the name column. You can chain this onto an association, but not onto an instance. So, as meagar very agressively pointed out by downvoting the other answers (including Mori's deleted answer), in a `has_one` relationship you can't chain this on the association (because it's not an association in that case). However, you could build a custom scope, like this:

```
class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :bar
  scope :bar_name, lambda {Bar.select(:name).where(:foo_id=> id)}
end
```

The above is untested so you may have to tweak it, but generally speaking that approach would allow you to do something like:

```
foo.bar_name
```

...without loading all the columns from Bar.

Comment: Would a scope for this be representative? A scope generally returns an ActiveRecord::Relation, empty or not. A method would be more appropriate (or delegate?)

Comment: Well, this is a chain of ActiveRecord query methods so I think it is returning a relation - the only weird thing about it is it would be returning a relation built on the Bar class instead of the Foo class - but once you've gone to `something.otherthing.where()` you're kind of doing that anyway. Defining a method would also be a good way to accomplish this though. I've never needed to do something like this, so I don't really have a frame of reference as to which would be better or why.

Answer (score 1):

No, in the case of your `has_one`, but yes in the case of `has_many`.

The object returned for a `has_one` association isn't a scope onto which you can chain additional methods like `select`, like with a `has_many`. It's an actual instance of the model, and instantiating it will necessarily involve a `select *`.

If you want to select just the name, you'll have to access the `User` model directly and use `select`.

Conversely, if your `Foo` has many `users`, you could use `foo.users.select("name")` or any of the other chainable methods, as `foo.users` would be an *actual* ActiveRecord association, not an instance of a model.