# ActiveRecord: select for has_one

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have the following active record model:

```
class Dispatch < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :waypoint
end
```

When accessing the waypoint object, the generated query retrieves all columns from the model:

```
pry(main)> d.waypoint
Waypoint Load (0.5ms) SELECT `waypoints`.* FROM `waypoints`
WHERE `waypoints`.`waypointable_id` = <dispatch_id>
LIMIT 1
```

If I want to retrieve specific columns from the dispatch's waypoint then I should use the `select` scope for `has_one` [ApiDock reference, section 4.2.3](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#has-one-association-reference). Unfortunately, that approach throws a `NoMethodError`:

```
pry(main)> d = Dispatch.last
pry(main)> d.waypoint.select('latitude, longitude')
Waypoint Load (19.4ms)  SELECT `waypoints`.* FROM `waypoints`
WHERE `waypoints`.`waypointable_id` = <some_id> LIMIT 1
NoMethodError: private method `select' called for #<Waypoint:0x007fe77ed79c28>
```

What am I missing? I tried with ActiveRecord 4.0.11 and 4.2.0.

#### Edit

The underlying query should be something like this:

```
SELECT latitude, longitude FROM `waypoints`
WHERE `waypoints`.`waypointable_id` = <some_id>
LIMIT 1
```

I know I could just do

```
Waypoint.where(waypointable_id: <some_id>).select('latitude, longitude').last
```

but that misses the whole point of the `has_one` association. And since it is a feature specified in the docs then it should work properly, right?

Comment: Did you tried d.waypoint.pluck(:latitude, :longitude)

Comment: @pkrawat1 Yes, `undefined method pluck for #<Waypoint:0x007f853eb28160>`

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
Waypoint.select('latitude, longitude').where(...)
```

Activerecord `select` is a class method : http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#selecting-specific-fields

Comment: But I want to take advantage of the `has_one` association.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16111930/is-it-possible-to-ask-for-only-certain-columns-from-an-activerecord-association for why it is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
d.waypoint.as_json(only: [:latitude, :longitude])
```

Comment: That still loads all columns: `pry(main)> d.waypoint.as_json(only: [:latitude, :longitude])
  Waypoint Load (0.5ms)  SELECT waypoints.* FROM waypoints`

Answer (score 0):

By default has_one retrieves the whole object but if you need to override this you cannot call select on the retrieved object because select is a class method.

try ::

```
has_one :waypoint, -> { select "latitude, longitude"}
```

this will return by default only the latitude and longitude.